# Visual Studio 2008 Breakpoint will not be hit

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, release-mode

I have a bug that only occurs in release mode, which is a problem because I am not able to regularly debug my code. The breakpoint says "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." I have tried many of the other solutions people have posted about this problem, but none of them seem to work for release mode. Are there any suggestions on how to find a bug in release mode or how to regularly debug code in release mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable debug symbols in your project.

If this is a C++ Project, you need to do 2 things to get debug info:

1) In the "Project Settings" under "Configuration Properties" -> "C/C++" -> "General", you need to set "Debug Information Format" to "Program Database (/Zi)".

2) In the "Project Settings" under "Configuration Properties" -> "Linker" -> "Debugging" make sure you set the "Generate Debug Info" to "Yes (/DEBUG)".

Then, the build (compile and link) process will generate a PDB with debug info... typically next to your exe file but with a pdb extension.

Now when you run the project from Visual Studio, you should be able to debug and set breakpoints.

Other languages have similars settings although in slightly different locations.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This did generate a PDB, but I still am not able to debug my code, its giving the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: I think the problem is the files I am trying to debug are not a part of the .exe. For some reason in debug mode, they are a part of that .exe., which is also named something different

Comment: Are you building or using DLLs?  You will need to make sure those have debug information available too.

Comment: Are you sure the file you are trying to put a breakpoint in is part of your project where you set the debugging options?

Comment: Yes I am using DLLs, but the files I am interested in are not in the DLLs... And yes I am sure its in the correct project. I stay in the same project and switch between debug and release mode, which has been the problem

Comment: Can you set the breakpoint in DEBUG mode and is it hit?  Is the place where you are setting the breakpoint conditionally compiled code ?

Comment: You can optionally turn off optimizations with `#pragma optimize( "", off )` to see if the Release-Only issue is caused by the optimizer.

Comment: "... its giving the same error".  If you're generating a PDB but still getting the "symbols not loaded" error it sounds like perhaps the PDB file is in the wrong location.  Is it generated in the same "Release" folder the exe is in?

Comment: Yes, I can set the breakpoint in debug and it does get hit. It is the exact same file and location, just in release mode. And the PDB file is in the same location as the exe, which is in the Release folder. I just don't understand why it would allow you to debug the file in debug mode but not release mode...

Comment: I actually just needed to reboot, and it magically worked... Frustrating. But thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmmm... sometimes the Windows PDB Server for Debugging can crash and a reboot will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the release configuration does not build a .pdb file (which contains the symbols that cannot be loaded).  You can enable this option in your project properties.  Also be aware that your code will be optimized, by default.  This can affect breakpoints, so often, when I am debugging release builds, I will create several breakpoints (Since your symbols cannot be loaded, this is not your problem... yet).

If you are running the on the same computer that built the program, then it will usually find the .pdb file and source code.  If not, make sure that the .pdb file is in the same directory as your .exe so the runtime/debugger can find the symbols.